html_element() in rvest: How to check if a url has a certain element
I am trying to webscrape some addresses from urls and I am not sure if I am correctly making the variable that contains the specific element I want to check the url has :
addressParser <- function(url) {   
  hrefs <- read_html(url) %>%                                                   
    html_elements(".Directory-listLink") %>%     
    html_attr("href") 
  formattedHrefs <- gsub("../", "", hrefs, fixed = TRUE) 
  link <- paste(subway, formattedHrefs, sep = "/")
  addressLink <- read_html(url) %>%
    html_elements(".c-address") %>%
    html_elements("#address") %>%
    html_text2()
  dirlistLink <- read_html(url) %>% 
    html_elements(".Directory-listLink") 

  if (length(dirlistLink) == 0) {
    teaserLink <- read_html(url) %>% 
      html_elements(".Teaser-innerWrapper") 
    if (length(teaserLink) > 0) {

The error I am getting is the following:
Error during wrapup: argument is of length zero
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
